# Objective-C notation - UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I have the following method:

```
+(UINavigationBar*)insertTopbar
{
    UINavigationBar *navBar = [ [UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 44)];
    NSString* navBarPortraitBackgroundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"navBarPortraitBackground" ofType:@"png"];

    navBar.topItem.title = @"MyApp";

    UINavigationItem *navAdd = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];
    navAdd.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addFood)];

    navAdd.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(addFood)];


    [navBar pushNavigationItem:navAdd animated:YES];

    [[navBar appearance] setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:navBarPortraitBackgroundPath] forBarPosition:UIBarPositionTopAttached barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    return navBar;
}
```

And i implement it in some of my ViewControllers by writing `[self.view addSubview:[KalorieTopbar insertTopbar]];`

The problem is the line right before `return navBar`, when i try to set the appearence of the navBar. I think that there might be something wrong with my way of setting that, as i get the error: `No visible @interface for 'UINavigationBar' declares the selector 'appearance'`

Comment: Mads, the selected answer is incorrect. @cweinberger answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because a UINavigationBar instance does not have an appearance method.

The method setBackgroundImage:forBarPosition:barMetrics: is a method on a UINavigationBar instance as per Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uinavigationbar_class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006887-CH3-SW15)

So the line should be

```
[navBar setBackgroundImage: 
         [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:navBarPortraitBackgroundPath] 
      forBarPosition:UIBarPositionTopAttached 
      barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

This is new in IOS 7 and previously use the class method as per @cweinberger's answer

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense now!

Comment: This answer is incorrect. As per [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uinavigationbar_class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006887-CH3-SW16), is an `UIAppearanceContainer`, and `setBackgroundImage:forBarPosition:barMetrics:` is among the ones available for appearance customization.

Comment: @LeoNatan navBar is a UINavigationBar* and setBackgroundImage:forBarPosition:barMetrics applies to it. What is a UIAppearanceContainer?

Comment: `[UINavigationBar appearance]` returns a proxy object for `UINavigationBar`. You are clearly not familiar with appearance proxy. Time to familiarize yourself with it.

Comment: @LeoNatan What does setBackgroundImage:forBarPosition:barMetrics: do for the navBar ?

Comment: It changes sets a background image for a specified bar position and bar metrics. (?)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look into the documentation of UIAppearance: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfcm/UIAppearance/appearance

It is a class +method, not an instance -method. Therefore you need to call `[UINavigationBar appearance]` instead of `[navBar appearance]`.